# Fire event after loading innerHTML

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am attempting to fire an event after an innerHTML page is loaded via ajax using a click function, but I can't seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
var url;
var textUrl;
$('.linkQuestion').on('click', 'a', function() {
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    textUrl = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/RichText-javascript/richTextEditor.js?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAJRENG2ALKWZTWOLA&Expires=1352449392&Signature=Z5GHSw5NaBsDC1c2MwWQC32rVKo%3D&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzECEakAIaCSO9XKqmKgVa/ik%2BPvC1ZfmZEtAuf1MyMhvuXFkES0Io1tP3Lpcm85usfK%2B0/Df4yQYbvNhyT8wq9r7SajzJd%2Bx/luK5AvD08gJuNsXwWuH4S/8edxqJp42q4cmstHl3/ylAD%2BGgIP8IAQI5h6ZccsY4fbPpZryBt8VNtu/22qB53dTWjCwpNlPme6PyW7VDtRQlFBNNqcLfb2pYY6/fqI7jiMj8JgD341N%2BvwH4oSQbhApzRn0fRgzbJU6g8TxRCHCcdJs6le1VmF9vaZmLsng7xjtsBkC5h4djaWsufut1lpYRjgTQIUAn5ZS/d93/TmtRC5l9yNByyT0rqU/ukSAiQksUWgoyRq0r/Cp/QyDMg/GEBQ%3D%3D';
  $('.answers').load(url, function() {
    $.getScript(textUrl, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        console.log(data); //data returned from getScript
        console.log(textStatus); //return "success"
        console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I can't get the js to fire after loading ajax. Trying to figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: The js you are trying to load is shooting Access Denied, I guess you should have access rights to that js and server to get that js.

Comment: I didn't post the correct file path here because the link is too long. I do have the access. Editing the link now to the actual file path

Comment: Running a local server, the script that I am trying to load is in the code above

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood what you needed to do. getScript has a success callback

```
$('.linkQuestion').on('click', 'a', function() {

var url = $(this).attr('href');
var textUrl = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/RichText-javascript/richTextEditor.js';

$('.answers').load(url, function() {
    $.getScript(textUrl, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        console.log(data); //data returned from getScript
        console.log(textStatus); //return "success"
        console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
    });
});
```

});

Comment: THis is definitely on the right track. The js loads now but it links me to a different HTML page rather than using innerHTML

Comment: Still can't seem to get it to work toxicate. Just updated my code

Answer (score 2):

The jquery getscript method has also an callback function, just like the click function.

The following example is from the jquery manual:

```
$.getScript("ajax/test.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
   console.log(data); //data returned
   console.log(textStatus); //success
   console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
   console.log('Load was performed.');
   //fire your event here!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a third parameter for ajax.load "data".

load( url, [data], [callback] )

You might want to try to pass it as NULL or an empty object {}.

But if amazonaws.com isn't the domain you're running on, you probably have a problem with ajax. @see: same origin policy